# How to detect keys into games using c# program?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

let me explain well..
I'm trying to write a program that "listen" the keys pressed by keyboard WHILE I'm into a full-screen game..

I've used DirectInput yet, but it seems don't look into it..

E.g i'm pressing spacebar into game and my char jumps, but my program won't listen to my keys.. it won't record ANYTHING. Just waiting for pressing ._.

i'll be happy if someone can help me, maybe giving an hint like HowTo pressing "a" and result like "spacebar" (pressing "a" i want jump xD)

Can some one help me? **

Comment: Download XNA and look through the examples, that will have everything you need to get started.  Plus your games will run on xbox arcade, zune and windows phone 7 in addition to PC

Comment: Nah, tryied.. It works just by the program to the program, but i found half solution.. Now my question is the last half one:
How to simulate keypress using DirectInput..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to listen to keys sent to a separate application, you can [create a keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).

Comment: Lol, found my probl xD Was correct using DirectInput.. Needed administrative privileges xD

Your work too :]

Comment: That's only true if the other program is running as admin.  (because of UIPI)

Comment: Thanks :]
Can you solve my last problem too? ^^" Lefu, i can't find anything on Google or something else like that.. Even on Microsoft site.. T^T

Comment: necro, but for someone were asking for the same:
i were trying to attach my keyboard to psx1 emulator, that needed an injection and not a simple keyboard hook

i'd prefer to use the injection in code right now instead, not into the emulator (it's not so fast)

i were trying to cheat on jumping at square in Final Fantasy IX - ehehe